# How to set up Eloquent relationships to work with a 3-way pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a 3 way pivot table that ties a role to a user for a specific organization. Here's how the relevant tables are set up:

```
//users table
Schema::create('users', function($table)
{
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('username', 30)->index();
    //more (irrelevant) fields here
    $table->timestamps();
});

//roles table
Schema::create('roles', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name', 100)->index();
    $table->string('description', 255)->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});

//organizations table
Schema::create('organizations', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name', 255);
    $table->string('slug', 100);
    $table->text('description');
    $table->timestamps();
});

//organization user role table
Schema::create('organization_user_role', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('organization_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('organization_id')->references('id')->on('organizations')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Each user can belong to one or more organizations, with one or more roles. Roles are tied to *both* a user and an organization simultaneously. That is to say, a user must have a role in an organization in order to be associated with it.

This doesn't seem to fit the mold of the traditional many-to-many relationship pivot-table that works so well out-of-the-box with Eloquent. Can Eloquent handle this type of relationship, or do I need a new model dedicated to handling the relationship? Can someone please show me what the User, Organization, and Role models would look like to tie the 3-way pivot table relationships together with Eloquent?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot It works, however I wouldn't call it complete solution. Still you can build yours on top of that.

Comment: Hi @deczo! Your solution worked perfectly for me. Please change your comment to an answer, so that I can accept your solution. :)

Comment: Here you go. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out: http://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot

It works, however I wouldn't call it complete solution. Still you can build yours on top of that.